# Nextjs useContext retrieving default values instead of values set by provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am using nextj with useContext to access my users data globally. I have set up the context here:

```
const UserContext = createContext(null);
export const UserDataContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [nombre, setNombre] = useState('New User');

  const userContext = {nombre}
  const setUserContext = {setNombre};
    
  return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ userData: userContext, setUserData: setUserContext}}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
};

export const useUserData = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

When I try to access this context using a child component like below:

```
import { useUserData } from '../components/context/userContext.js';
function Home() {
const userData = useUserData();
console.log(userData)

return(<></>)
}
```

I get null in the console logs instead of actually getting nombre and setNombre. Could you help me what I did wrong? Please let me know if you need any more information.

I tried writing the code in tsx but no luck

here is my Layout.tsx file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {UserDataContextProvider, UserDataContextConsumer} from './context/userContext.js';
import Navbar from './Navbar'; 
import Footer from './Footer';


export default function Layout(props: any) {

    return (
        <div>
            <UserDataContextProvider>
                    <Navbar />
                    {
                        props.children
                    }
                    <Footer></Footer>
            </UserDataContextProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is `Layout.tsx` is your root layout?